# How can I redirect from 404 error page to home page in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new in react and I just want to know how I can redirect the user from 404 Error page to the home page here's my project repo on GitHub [The project Github repository](https://github.com/Ahmed-Nasser/bloger)

Here's my routes code

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home';
import About from './components/about';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import NotFound from './components/404';

class Routes extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
            <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/about' component={About}  />
            <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
            <Route component = {NotFound}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Your GitHub link is a 404 not found.

Comment: @enkrates Sorry due, It was a private repo my mistake, now it's public give it a shot

Comment: So if the url is not mapped to any route, do you want to redirect to the home page?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to immediately redirect from a 404 to the home page (without ever seeing that `NotFound` component), you can replace the last Route (`<Route component = {NotFound}/>`) with this code:

`<Redirect to="/" />`

That should catch any paths that don't match the other routes, just as the NotFound route was before, but instead of rendering a component, it'll send the user over to the home page.